# SQL display only the highest values of a count function

Tags: mysql, sql, count, distinct-values

```
Select Distinct id as personID, count(tid) as Sales
From salesTable
Group by personID;
```

Current Results are: (I need the top sales to only show.)

```
 personID  | Sales
_____________________
   1000      | 2
   1020      | 1
   1040      | 2
   1060      | 1
   1080      | 2
   1140      | 1
   1160      | 1
   _________________
```

The salesTable looks like this:

```
id  | tid
_________
1000|201
1020|202
1040|203
1000|204
1060|205
1080|206
1040|207
1080|208
1140|209
1160|210
```

My desired results should look like this:

```
personID  | Sales
_____________________
   1000      | 2
   1040      | 2
   1080      | 2
  _________________
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select  id as personID
,       count(tid) as Sales
From    salesTable
group by 
        id
having  count(tid) =
        (
        select  max(Sales)
        from    (
                select  count(tid) as Sales
                from    salesTable
                group by
                        id
                ) SubQueryAlias
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly simpler and ordered:

```
SELECT id as personID
      ,count(tid) AS Sales
FROM   salesTable
GROUP  BY id
HAVING count(tid) =
   (
   SELECT count(tid)
   FROM   salesTable
   GROUP  BY id
   ORDER  BY count(tid) DESC
   LIMIT  1
   )
ORDER  BY personID;
```

[->SQLfiddle demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65046/7)